# Catch error message in ANGULAR interceptor

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to create centralized error handler in both API and client side, but angular interceptor never catches the error description model. The error message in interceptor is always:

> "Http failure response for url: 0 Unknown Error".

The error handler in the API always catches every error and exception. When I use Postman, error model is shown regularly.

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
            {
                errorApp.Run(async context =>
                {
                    var errorFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    var exception = errorFeature.Error;                    

                    var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
                    {
                        Instance = $"urn:myorganization:error:{Guid.NewGuid()}"
                    };

                    if (exception is BadHttpRequestException badHttpRequestException)
                    {
                        problemDetails.Title = "Invalid request";
                        problemDetails.Status = (int)typeof(BadHttpRequestException).GetProperty("StatusCode",
                            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(badHttpRequestException);
                        problemDetails.Detail = badHttpRequestException.Message;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        problemDetails.Title = "An unexpected error occurred!";
                        problemDetails.Status = 500;
                        problemDetails.Detail = exception.Message.ToString(); 
                    }

                    // log the exception etc..

                    context.Response.StatusCode = problemDetails.Status.Value;
                    context.Response.WriteJson(problemDetails, "application/problem+json");
                });
            });
```

this is angular interceptor:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        delay(0),
        map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            this.Loader = true;
                       
            return event;
        }),
        catchError((error: any) => {                
            console.log('error--->>>', error);                
            return throwError(error);
        }),
        finalize(() =>{
            this.Loader = false;
        }));
}
```

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is your API hosted on a server or running locally (i.e. localhost)?

Comment: locally, but I have tryed on a server, same thing happens

Comment: are you getting any console error?
Last time when I encountered `0: Unknown error`, it was due to cross-origin access. Since you are running locally, it shouldn't be the case, but again the ports could be different, so just to be double sure if you are also not getting the same error in console, can you check that.

Comment: yes, there is CORS error and also net::ERR_FAILED error

Comment: Well, then there you go. It's a server side issue. You need to send cross-origin access header in your response. I don't know about the .net framework how you do it, but some googling should help you out and should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: this happens only for bad requests(error in application and so on), so i would exclude that option.

Comment: What exactly does the console say, can you please post here? Along with that can you also post the response and response headers you are getting from the server (from the console->network tab)?
If you are receiving an error code in response header from the server, then we need to look into the full implementation of your interceptor and then maybe I can have a better view of what is going on and try to help further.